# Permits in iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, permissions

HI,
I want to create i file in the iPhone application.
I try it but i have a anomaly.
In my pc the file is correctly written.
In other pc with the same program the file wasn't exist.
In the iPhone device the file not exist.
But the strange think thing is that i haven't any error for the app in the all case.
Do you have a idea?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Read [this section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html) for information about file management. If you are going to do iPhone development, it is a very good idea to read the entire iPhone Application Programming Guide at the very least.